# Number of connections for a graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Suppose we have a graph $G(12,0.7)$ where 12 is the number of nodes and 0.7 is the probability of an edge being present. So total number of edges = $\binom{12}{2} = 66$

**Q1 (SOLVED):** What is the expected number of friends for Node A (let's say they are labeled A through L)?

My approach is no friends + 1 friend + 2 friends + ... + 12 friends

= $0.3*66 + 0.7*0.3^65 + ... + 0.7^{12}*0.3^{54}$

What is wrong with this?

**Q2:** What is the probability that 2 nodes have exactly 1 common friend?

My approach: A and B connects to exactly C, and A and B cannot connect to the another node together. Any clues on how to approach this?

Comment: Q1 should just be 0.7*11 or ~8 firends as each edge has a 70% chance of being there and there are 11 nodes which you can connect to.

Comment: Woah. Thanks. Didn't know it was that simple. I did it with probability which is wrong. Any clues for Q2?

Comment: Q2 is a bit tougher, let me get a paper and pencil

Comment: I am not sure about Q2, I assumed you can only have one set of "2 nodes have exactly 1 common friend". According to that, you cannot have that part connected to the rest of the graph. Which means that you can have 12C2 possibilities for any 3 nodes. For the other 9 nodes I cannot figure how to calculate the combinations.

Comment: @stackErr what about (number of ways to connect A and B to one other node)/ (no of ways to connect everything)?

Comment: It seems like a pretty tough one.  I was about to post an answer only to realize that something was incorrect at the last moment.  But maybe it's easy and I can't see it...What difficulty should we expect ?  Are you in an advanced course or more standard-type course ?

Comment: @manuellafond Just a college course question. I asked someone for help and I seem to have figured it out. I just need to multiply for the cases where the remaining nodes do not touch A and B + cases where it touches A only + case where it touches B only, and each node has that probability so we need to raise it to the power of the remaining nodes.

Comment: @user3511965 A clarification about Q2: Do you mean "any two nodes in the graph have exactly one common neighbor" or "at least one ordered pair of nodes such that they are a part of exactly one triangle"?

Comment: @talegari I may misinterpret your definition but it's two specified nodes have exactly 1 other node that connects to both of them. So the hard part is determining how to configure all the remaining nodes.

Comment: Ah so you mean that for two fixed nodes $A$ and $B$, what is the probability that $A$ and $B$ have exactly one common neighbor ?  This is different from asking for the probability that some pair of vertices have exactly one common neighbor (not necessarily $A$ and $B$ but any pair of vertices), which seems hard since the events in which pairs of vertices have 1 common neighbor are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE : here I assume the question is to find, for two fixed vertices $A,B$ that are given, the probability that they have exactly one common neighbor.  The more general problem of giving the probability there there is at least one pair of vertices with exactly one neighbor (not necessarily $A,B$) is a tougher one and an answer to that would be welcome.

Let $E_C$ denote the event that a fixed vertex $C$ is the only common neighbor of $A$ and $B$.
If we assume that $A,B$ both are neighbors of $C$, 
$A$ can have $0, 1, \ldots, 9$ neighbors other than $B$ and $C$, and if $A$ has say $k$ neighbors, then $B$ has probability $0.3^k$ of not having any of these as neighbors.
Then

$P(E_C) = .7^2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{9}{9 \choose k}0.7^k0.3^{9 - k}0.3^k $

Informally, this means $P(E_C)$ = $P(A,B$ neighbors with $C$) $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^9 P(A$ has $k$ neighbors$)P(B$ has none of them as neighbors$)$.

Now, $C$ can take on 9 different values.  And for some other vertex $D$, the event that $C$  is the only common neighbor of $A,B$ is mutually exclusive with the event that $D$ is.  Therefore, we can just sum this probability over every vertex, and the probability that $A,B$ have exactly one common neighbor is $9 * P(E_C) \approx 0.01$

Here is [a very lazy way to get this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=.7%5E2+%2a+%28sum+%289+choose+k%29+%2a+0.7%5Ek+%2a+0.3%5E%289+-+k%29+%2a+0.3%5Ek%2C+k+%3D+0+to+9%29+%2a+9).

Comment: This assumes and counts the possibilities that another two vertices (not A,B, and C) can still have one common friend. +1 Since it is technically a correct answer and OP hasn't clarified Q2

Comment: Indeed, it should be noted that $A,B$ need to be fixed.  I understood from OP's comments that it is indeed the case (as stated, we are given two specified vertices).  If we try to look for the probability that at least one pair of vertices have exactly one common neighbor, then I'm lost.  I'd absolutely love to see answer to this tougher question, and I suggest OP leaves this question unanswered just to see if someone has a solution.

Comment: I might have a solution if you can help me figure out how many ways there are to connect upto 9 vertices with a degree of maximum 1 with a 70% chance of an edge

Comment: Let me rephrase question 2: What is the probability of having one vertex with degree 2 and all the other vertices with a max degree of 1?

Comment: Ah that could be a question of its own...It does not seem obvious !